# parse json string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following Json string

```
{ "Users" : [ 
    { "Name" : "user99",
      "Value" : "test"
    },
    { "Name" : "test2",
      "Value" : "test"
    }
 ] 
}
```

I am trying to parse it and print out each name and value - what is the easiest way to do this ? 
I tried jQuery.parseJSON but I do not know how to use it I guess

Sample code would be great

Comment: From where are you obtaining this string?

Comment: What happens if you use `jQuery.parseJSON`? Have you had a look at the example? There is not much what you can do with that function ;)

Comment: my application queries a database and builds the json string for processing

Comment: How are you obtaining this string?

Comment: Just so you know, a more compact format for the same data is the following: `{"Users": {"user99" : "test2", "test2" : "test"}...]`. This format keys the users by their "Name".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
var json = '{"Users":[{"Name":"user999","Value":"test"},{"Name":"test2","Value":"test"}]}';

var json_parsed = $.parseJSON(json);

for (var u = 0; u < json_parsed.Users.length; u++){
    var user = json_parsed.Users[u];
    $('body').append($('<p>').html('User: '+user.Name+'<br />Value: '+user.Value));
}
```

Results in:

```
<p>User: user999<br />Value: test</p>
<p>User: test2<br />Value: test</p>
```

jsFiddle Example: http://jsfiddle.net/bradchristie/XtzjZ/1/

Answer (score 2):

You actually have an array of objects so..

```
var obj = $.parseJSON(string);

var users = obj.users;    

for x in users {
    alert(users[x].Name);
    alert(users[x].Value);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery.parseJSON, here's an example:

```
var jsonString = '{"key":"value","otherkey":"othervalue"}';
data = $.parseJSON(jsonString);
alert(data.key); // Shows: value
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
var str = '{"Users":[{"Name":"user999","Value":"test"},{"Name":"test2","Value":"test"}]}';
str = eval('('+str+')');
alert(str.Users[0].Name);

//var str = '{"x":{"a":"1"}}';
//alert(str.x.a);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the JSON you have given, `$.parseJSON` should return an object, `myObj`, that can be accessed like so:

```
var users = myObj.Users,
    user0_name = users[0].Name;
```