# how to get the content/ string value when i parse the url?

Tags: android, xml-parsing

```
String url="http://graph.facebook.com/GHost"; 
URL objUrl = new URL(url);
InputStream is= objUrl.openStream();
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();   
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(is));
String str=doc.getTextContent();<<<<<<<<<----------- getting null value
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(str);<<<<---------making exception error
String id = object.getString("id");
if do open the url the content is like below
{
    "id": "3965568744555",
    "name": "GHost",
    "picture": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/373042_396504583708761_1625984_s.jpg",
    "link": "http://www.facebook.com/GHost",
    "likes": 70,
    "cover": {
    "cover_id": 493579484270,
    "source": "http://a3.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/s720x720/396014_493579484001270_177795_n.jpg",
    "offset_y": 0
},
```

how do i write the code at String str=? and finally i want to get the id value. please any help?

Comment: have you given the INTERNET permission in manifest ?

Comment: You are trying to parse json data in DOM XML format..

Comment: see my answer..and change your logic to convert input stream to String

Answer (score 0):

you can parse the file... with String concat functions .. 
[parse json string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071115/parse-json-string)

Answer (score 0):

use below code

```
String line;
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
while ((line= r.readLine()) != null) {
    total.append(line);
}

String str = total.toString();
```

instead of

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();   
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(is));
String str=doc.getTextContent();
```

Comment: I hope value of inputStream is not null.